# How to embedd a gpg key in static Nikola websites?

Tags: gnupg, public-key, nikola

What is the best way to include gpg public keys on a website, which is generated by the [Nikola website generator](http://getnikola.com/)?

- It should be easy to import by visitors.
- Nikola must not the key while rendering the page.

Edit: After 7 months I think the ideal solution makes use of [WKD](https://wiki.gnupg.org/WKD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a default, all files within the `files/` folder will be copied 1:1 into the output files. So if you're using the default config: to have your public key on your page, you can simply store it in `files/key.txt` and it will be available as `https://yourpage.com/key.txt`.

In the `conf.py` you can find the following:

````
# One or more folders containing files to be copied as-is into the output.
# The format is a dictionary of {source: relative destination}.
# Default is:
# FILES_FOLDERS = {'files': ''}
# Which means copy 'files' into 'output'```
````